# Сериализация свойства коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такой класс:

```
public class ChapterCollection : ObservableCollection<ChapterVM>
{
    public bool? IsSelectedAll
    {
        get { return _isSelectedAll; }
        set
        {                
            _isSelectedAll = value;                
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSelectedAll)));
        }
    }
}
```

При его сериализации в XML свойство `IsSelectedAll` не сериализуется. Только коллекция объектов `ChapterVM`.

Как сериализовать свойство?

---

Сериализация происходит так:

```
public static void SerializeToXml(string path, object saveObject)
{
    var formatter = new XmlSerializer(saveObject.GetType());
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fs, saveObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: как ты сериализуешь?

Comment: @Gardes, поясните может для чего правка заголовка? Вы хотите сказать что проблема в `Nullable`-типе и при замене его на обычный `bool` проблема уйдет?

Comment: ‎Коллекции обычно не являются хорошим местом для дополнительных свойств. Кроме того, во время сериализации, эти свойства будут игнорироваться, если сериализуемый объект выглядит как коллекция.

Comment: @sp7, вы рекомендуете использовать автору композицию вместо наследования?

Comment: @Андрей, в данном случае да. Проще создать некий враппер, в который положить его текущую коллекцию и данное свойство, а потом сериализовать данный объект.

Comment: @Grundy, Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @sp7, Использование враппера единственный вариант?

Comment: @maxwell, либо реализуйте интерфейс [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболее простым решением является отказ от наследования в пользу композиции. Действительно, логично предположить что `ChapterCollection` не просто "является" коллекцией `ChapterVM`, а содержит в себе коллекцию `ChapterVM` и также некоторые другие свойства, как признак выделенности элементов коллекции и т.п.
Зы. Недаром умные книги по проектированию пишут

> Предпочитайте композицию наследованию

---

Если всё же вы намерены оставить наследование, для переопределения действий сериализатора необходимо реализовать интерфейс [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx). Сделать это можно примерно так:

```
public class ChapterCollection : ObservableCollection<Chapter>, IXmlSerializable
{
    bool? _isSelectedAll;
    public bool? IsSelectedAll
    {
        get { return _isSelectedAll; }
        set
        {
            _isSelectedAll = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSelectedAll)));
        }
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement();

        // Читаем из потока дополнительные свойства вручную
        IsSelectedAll = reader.ReadElementContentAsBoolean(nameof(IsSelectedAll), "");
        // Читаем элементы коллекции
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Chapter));
        while (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            Add((Chapter)ser.Deserialize(reader));

        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // Сериализуем дополнительные свойства вручную
        writer.WriteStartElement(nameof(IsSelectedAll));
        writer.WriteValue(IsSelectedAll);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        // Сериализуем элементы коллекции
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Chapter));
        foreach (var ch in this)
            ser.Serialize(writer, ch);
    }
}
```

---

Дополню ответ вариантом сериализации при композиции.

Наш класс коллекции превращается в такой:

```
public class ChapterCollection
{
    public bool? IsSelectedAll { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Chapter> Collection { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Chapter>();
}
```

Обратите внимание, создать экземпляр нужно обязательно вручную, сериализатор не может создавать "кастомные" коллекции, поэтому он не заполнит ее: `= new ObservableCollection<Chapter>();`
Но зато открывать свойство коллекции на запись (`set;`) не нужно.

Теперь вы можете использовать `Linq`, но придется указать имя этого свойства-коллекции:

```
myChapterCollection.Collection.Select(...);
```

Если вы реализуете `IEnumerable<>`, то сериализатор опять начнет думать что это коллекция и потеряет свойства, да еще к тому же потребует реализовать нетипизированный метод `Add(object)`, что уже некрасиво и добавляет некоторую хрупкость.

PS: благодаря утиной типизации C# можно все же добавить маленький кусочек сахара, добавив в класс метод:

```
public IEnumerator<Chapter> GetEnumerator()
    => ((IEnumerable<Chapter>)Collection).GetEnumerator();
```

это хоть и не даст воспользоваться LINQ на экземпляре класса, но позволит упростить код `foreach`:

```
// myChapterCollection.Collection писать не требуется:
foreach (var chapter in myChapterCollection)
    ...
```

Comment: @Andrey, А как сериализовать свойство при композиции? Пометил аттрибутом `[XmlElement]` — не помогло.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Ошибки не было. Полагаю, что это произошло из-за реализации интерфейса IEnumerable, дабы были доступны методы LINQ.

Comment: @maxwell, вопрос закрыт, я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, отказался от композиции в сторону реализации `IXmlSerializable`. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @maxwell, дополнил ответ вариантом сериализации при композиции